# AWS S3 Glacier - how to specify for a vault storage class as DEEP_ARCHIVE in PowerShell?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I created a vault via New-GLCVault, but when it came to upload a file there I understood that I didn't know how to specify desired storage class for the vault. I need to place my file to a DEEP_ARCHIVE vault, and here come 2 questions:

1. How can I see the storage class associated with particular vault in PowerShell?
2. How can I specify the desired storage class when I create the vault and(or) upload there my files?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of Amazon Glacier:

1. The 'original' Amazon Glacier that uses Vaults and Archives. It is slow and very difficult to use.
2. Amazon S3 **storage classes** that allow you to use standard S3 API calls, but gain pricing benefits by using Glacier storage classes (which are actually *cheaper* than the 'original' Glacier).

It appears that you are attempting to use a Storage Class (#2 above) with the Amazon Glacier service (#1 above), which won't work.

Instead, just use standard S3 API calls and specify: `StorageClass='DEEP_ARCHIVE'`

This method also means **you don't need to do anything with Vaults.**

Comment: Does it mean that I should use New-S3Bucket and Write-S3Object to upload my file to Deep Archive storage?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Include the Storage Class when performing the upload.